# What is the use of Nodejs mongodb driver keepAlive option?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having hard time understanding `keepAlive` option passed to nodeJS mongo driver.
this [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/MongoClient.html) says `keepAlive` takes boolean value and `keepAliveInitialDelay` is `used to wait before initiating keepAlive on the TCP socket`

this [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/connecting/connection-settings/) says `keepAlive` takes an integer value and reads `The number of milliseconds to wait before initiating keepAlive on the TCP socket.`

I tried using both and failed to find any difference also I tried with both `true` and `false` values for `keepAlive` and tried 0,1 and 30000(default) for `keepAliveInitialDelay`.

1. what is the correct way to use `keepAlive`?
2. what does "*initiating*" `keepAlive` do? or what is the use of `keepAlive` option?
3. why did it not make any difference even after setting `keepAlive` to `false` or settings it to `0` or `1`?
4. [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/connecting/connection-settings/) here state that `keepAlive` affects artefacts -> `Server, ReplicaSet, Mongos`. so to which option does it map to at server side [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-options)?

I'm using mongo driver V3.3 and mongo atlas V4.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP keep-alive mechanism is described [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html). It is used for:

- Checking for dead peers
- Preventing disconnection due to network inactivity

When keep-alive is enabled, the driver instructs the network stack to periodically send ping packets to the server on the established connection. If the server's network stack does not respond, the connection is flagged as failed.

Without keep-alive, the driver wouldn't find out about some of the network issues until after the application issued a query (and was waiting for it to be executed).

The driver sets the network stack options [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/src/cmap/connect.ts#L268) using [setKeepAlive](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay).

To see whether keep-alives are being sent, you need to use a tool like `tcpdump` to inspect traffic on the connections established by the driver.

The server [uses the system-wide keep-alive value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-mongodb-deployments) if it is under 300 seconds, otherwise sets keep-alive interval to 300 seconds.

Comment: is this bi-directional? Does mongo server pings the driver as well? to check connection status? that's my 4th question actually.

Comment: or how does the server(specifically mongo int this case) will know a connection should be closed as the client is not alive any more? -> if client explicitly could not close the connection due to some unforeseen events.

Comment: Server uses 300 seconds or system value if lower.

Comment: so server should identify dead clients and close the connection right?